# Save and retrieve images - Ios

Tags: ios, image, sqlite

I want to save some images on a folder on my local machine (example documents folder). And then save the url in sqlite database. How can i do this ? I also want to retrieve the images and then display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can navigate to the Documents folder for your application and then you can save the `UIImage` by using `UIImagePNGRepresentation`, which returns `NSData`.

Sample code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imgPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); // image is the UIImage you want to save
[imageData writeToFile:imgPath atomically:YES];
```

Then you just have to put the path/filename in your database and retrieve it when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Get the NSData of the image:
`NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);`
 and then write to a file:
`[imageData writeToFile:filepath atomically:YES];`